# Why Google Chrome console throws "SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" when inputted (

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Google Chrome's console, when we input

```
(
```

and Enter, Chrome says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" Why? Input is just "(", including no "}".

We get the same error when we input

```
console.log(
```

There's no "}"!!!

Next token should be arguments list or ")" so error message should be "Expected arguments list" or "Unclosed (" or something.

And I wanna know, is console input parsed as `StatementList(opt)` (defined in ECMA-262)?

Comment: Care to post some of the code that is throwing said error?

Comment: @Seth: He did, it's just not easy to see.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989226/why-does-result-in-false-in-a-javascript-console

Answer (score 22):

**Edit:**  I found the exact code that gets evaluated. The code is in "src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js".

Before the Chrome console evaluates your code, it wraps it in a `with` block to bring the command-line functions into scope. So what you type is actually evaluated inside braces. The unexpected "}" token is the one put in automatically by Chrome.

The code that Chrome passes to `eval` is

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
    <your code here>
};
```

Because it's a simple text substitution, the following example works and the result is an object which you can expand to see the `answer` property:

```
} 0, { answer: 42
```

Which (reformatted) is equivalent to:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
}
0, { answer: 42 };
```

The `}` at the beginning closes the `with` block. The `0,` part is necessary to force the object literal to be parsed as an expression instead of another block. Then, the `{ answer: 42` is the beginning of an object literal that gets closed by the inserted `}` token.

For more fun, here are some other inputs that work (and their results):

```
> }{ // an empty block, so no value
  undefined

> }!{ // !{} === false
  false

> }!!{ // !!{} === true
  true

> } +{ valueOf: function() { return 123; }
  123
```

Comment: +1 for what amounts to clever SQL-injection with Javascript ;-) That `0` *is* most curious...

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Hmm... It's very tricky...
So Chrome seems to parse `'{' + text + '}'`. 
I tried
    `}; '10 '+{`
and get `"10 [object Object]"`, which is the same result as Firefox.

Comment: Wow! Great! I saw InjectedScriptSource.js line 280 to find exactly what you're saying! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Cameron: it would be a JavaScript-injection attack then ;-)