# Why does }!{ result in False in a JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript

If you put `}!{` in your JavaScript console in Chrome, as a result you will get `false`.

Why don't we get an error?

Comment: Hmm, Chrome/V8 bug or JavaScript language nuance?  Could go either way!

Comment: `}!!{` gives `true` and `};{` gives `undefined`

Comment: In IE9 dev tools, the console gives "Syntax error" for `}!{`, `}!!{`, and `};{`

Comment: Syntax error in Firefox as well, seems to be a bug in Chrome, it's not valid syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602856/why-google-chrome-console-throws-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-when-inputted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is because Chrome wraps anything you enter into the console with another piece of code.

The code it wraps with (at the time of writing) is as follows:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
    // Your code here.
}
```

Entering `}!{` closes the code block brace, and makes a new (negated) object at the end.

As you can see for youself in the console `!{}` returns `false`.

---

I went through quite a lengthy investigative process to find the answer to this, my original comments are preserved below

**Original Answer:**

Just a theory; I imagine the code entered in the console being called inside a function

`function execUserCode() { code }`

What you're doing is creating

`function execUserCode() { }!{ }`

The console is returning the last result, which is actually `!{ }` = `false`

---

**Edit:**

Lots of comments about how this is probably wrong. I agree. It's just a theory.

I like these kind of puzzles so I had a dig through the Chromium source, it's a bit much for me but I'll leave some pointers in case anyone else has a stab.

The JS console is called the "inspector" and can be found here:

`chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/`

I've been looking at `inspector/front-end/ConsoleView.js` and I think I found a bit of where the user code is executed.

```
evaluateUsingTextPrompt: function(expression, showResultOnly)
{
    this._appendCommand(expression, this.prompt.text, false, showResultOnly);
},
```

---

## The reason!

Little brainwave. I did this in the console

```
> myEval = eval
> eval = function(str) { console.log(str); myEval(str) }
> }!{
```

Result:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
}!{
}
```

I was close, but now we have the answer :)

The code is generated in `chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js` currently around line 440.

Comment: I don't think that is the case... `return 'test';` creates a syntax error in the console. And I don't think they would build the function using string concatenation, they would use the `Function` constructor.

Comment: Nice theory, but why so many upvotes and accept this without any proof? If this assumption were right, doing `}("test");{` should return `undefined` then, since the last expression would be just `{}`.

Comment: @kapep I agree with you, I'm disappointed it's accepted, I'd like to see more (better) theories myself. I just spent 15 minutes crawling the chromium source and my eyes hurt :(

Comment: Yes, `console.log(arguments)` gives ReferenceError. Maybe it is like you say, but it is a simple block instead of a function.

Comment: @kapep Updated, got a real answer now.

Comment: Ok, I also just found some strange behaviour here: The block `{1;}` returns `1` but `{2;{};}` returns `2`.. so an empty block seems to be ignored, which explains why `!{}` is actually returned but also in the above comment it is the previous `"test"` statement. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation about what a block statement should return.

Comment: `!{}` is false. `{}` is undefined. `!undefined` is true... *brain explodes*

Comment: It's not about undefined though, `{1;undefined}` returns `undefined` just as expected. Something special about empty block I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess. If the script is enclosed in `{}` and executed using `eval`, this will happen.

user script:  `"}!{"`

enclosed in `{}`:  `"{}!{}"`

then `eval("{}!{}")` gives `false`

So I guess this is what happens in browser console.

Comment: `};console.log("TEST");{` outputs `TEST` which would support your guess!

Comment: @Diode, pretty close. I managed to get the real reason, its at the end of my answer.