# while loop prints 1 up and to 10, but gives back 11

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am again working in CodeAcademy and I have continued along and now working with while loops. However, I am working a little bit in the scratchpad, and I've noticed something weird to me.
This code right below this text:

```
var counter = 1;

while(counter <= 10){
    console.log(counter);
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Gives this as a result.
Why does 11 pop up at the bottom. It shouldn't be there. Is it counting 0. Or is there some more bitter explanation to this. Would be glad to get some help, thanks :P

**Result:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
==> 11
```

Comment: i am getting only 1 to 10 only

Comment: even I am getting only 1 to 10 :P, post your complete js code

Comment: Same here, I only get 1 to 10: http://jsfiddle.net/gAu2x/

Comment: I am also getting from 1 to 10 only... then instead of **counter** use another variable identifier and check.. might get messed somewhere..

Comment: The printed values MUST be 1 to 10, but `counter` will contain `11` after the loop finishes.

Comment: How's that possible, why will counter contain 11 when I start counting from 1? Also**this is all the code I have, there is no more than this :(

Comment: Because of this statement: `counter = counter + 1;`, it increases the value of `counter` by one and assigns it to `counter` again.

Comment: Ok, so how would you do it then. Getting 1--10 and a 10 as a result?

Comment: just to confirm.. it is not printing 11 but at the end counter is having 11.. is it your problem?? if so please understand your code flow properly why it is having 11.. because after you print 10 you are increasing counter by one again..

Comment: Is there any way possible to avoid this. Is there any way to print 12345678910 and have a final result 10? instead of 11?

Comment: This is not the standard behaviour of Javascript : the scratchpad of codeacademy seems to show hints about variable states. Here the final lines just indicates that `counter` now contains `11`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am testing in Firefox and it is logging what the OP says.. and this is my take on it.

var counter = 1;

```
1 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
2 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
3 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
4 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
5 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
6 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
7 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
8 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
9 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
10 is it <= 10 yes, print add 1
11  <-- prints it.
```

The while loop knows of the "counter" as it is passed in, not as it is declared 'after' or within the loop. It doesn't back reference. So it still has to go thru again.

```
before: 1

after: 2

before: 2

after: 3

before: 3

after: 4

before: 4

after: 5

before: 5

after: 6

before: 6

after: 7

before: 7

after: 8

before: 8

after: 9

before: 9

after: 10

before: 10

after: 11
```

Comment: Aha, I see... :) Is there some way to ditch the pprinting of the after 11 value? Any way at all?

Answer (score 2):

This is the behavior of console. It will return the result of the last expression in some cases

```
var counter = 1, t="loop";

while(counter <= 10){
    console.log(counter);
    counter = counter + 1;
    t = "loop end";
}
```

will give you

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
"loop end"
```

Comment: If you want to know more about it, you can go through this question. This is the reason why console behaves like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989226/why-does-result-in-false-in-a-javascript-console

Answer (score 0):

You should do this.

```
var counter = 0;

while(counter < 10){
    console.log(counter);
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

while(counter <= 10) says while counter is less than or equals to 10 it will do the loop.That's why number 11 is also printed.

Answer (score -1):

The condition 'counter <= 10' allows flow to enter body of the loop when count is equal to 10. You're incrementing the count in the body so the final count will be 11.

Change the condition to 'counter < 10' and the result will be 10.

This will result in 1 - 10 and leave count as 10:

```
var counter = 0;

while(counter < 10){
    counter = counter + 1;
    console.log(counter);
}
```

Comment: bad idea... you will get up to 9 only

Comment: No, @louisbros, you're checking the value AFTER the loop ends, that's why it's 10.

Comment: I don't think that's totally correct louisbros. I only get up to 9 if I do that. I want to get up to ten and a result 10. If you have some idea on how to do that?

Comment: I was just explaining why the value of count is 11 after the loop finishes.

Comment: If you want to see the 10 put the log message after incrementation

Comment: Okey, I see. I guess this though is quite nooby so thanks for baring with me. :)